# Backup using rsync apparently does not remove files and folders that does not exist anymore on source

Tags: rsync

I'm using very handy `rsync` command which allows me to have a backup of particular folders on a specific volumes.

I call `rsync` with following parameters:

`rsync -avzP`

To be explicit, when I want to do a backup of all pictures and Lightroom catalogs I call:

`rsync -avzP /Volumes/SLICK-2TB/Pictures /Volumes/SLICK-PICTURES-BACKUP`

So **SLICK-2TB** is my *source* drive and **SLICK-PICTURES-BACKUP** is my *destination* drive.

My problem is, whenever I delete / remove a file on source, the change is not reflected on destination. In other words, all new stuff will be always archived on backup volume, but things that don't exist on the source, will be left intact on destination.

Is there a particular attribute that I could add to `-avzP` that will help me achieve / solve the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `--delete` argument to delete the files on the destination.

Also consider using `--dry-run` first to make sure you aren't deleting the wrong files. I guess the reason --delete is not a default argument (or part of -a) is that it can wipe out the destination if it's not set correctly.